# Redirect Issue after appending number to permalink

Tags: wordpress

I'm current having an issue with wordpress on my site I had a page /ideas

I wanted to create a new custom post type "ideas" to have different settings, to do this I altered the /ideas page to be /ideas2 to come back to it later.

Now when trying to access /ideas I get a redirect loop between ideas and ideas2

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the permalinks from the Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks page. It should fix the redirect issue.